# PCB footprint design of the ADMP401

Tags: pcb-design, kicad

I am creating a PCB in KiCad and I am trying to create a footprint for my mic, the ADMP401. When creating the footprint and running the design rules checker, it says I have a clearance issue with the pads on the footprint I created for the ADMP401 and it needs to be at least .2 mm. Im, not sure how to fix this. I have attached the datasheet.
https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/ADMP401.pdf

[image: ADMP401]

[image: Footprint]

[image: Sparkfun module]

Comment: I inserted a picture of the ADMP401 I am using. As you can see, this ADMP401 does not have the middle or two corner pins, only the 3 on the end. I am unsure how to figure out what size I need to make the holes and the pads on the footprint to not violate these rules.

Comment: Can you also post a picture of the footprint as displayed in the footprint editor?
IIRC there are also clearance settings in the pad menu (select pad, press E, one or two tabs to the right)

Comment: yep, just checked. there are clearance settings for pad-to-pad clearance, solder mask clearance and paste mask clearance. Your problem is likely the pad-to-pad clearance. The DRC error should mention the layer where the problem is...

Comment: Be careful you are not mixing measurements in inches (in) and millimeters (mm). Also, are you actually using the 0.5500 in x 0.400 in module (PCB) as you show, or do you want to use the much smaller component as described in the datasheet you have linked to?

Comment: Im not sure at this point, what I am using is pictured above, the ADMP401.

Comment: OK, so what you show in the last two pictures is the module, (that contains the smaller ADMP401 and other components). Very often vendors will name the module after the chip P/N. A few of the comments and answers give you the correct advice to just set up the 3-pin module as a 3-pin inline (or SIP) connector with 0.100 in (2.54 mm) pin spacing. Note that if you replace the 3-pin straight header with a right-angle type you could mount the module vertically and save space. Be sure to include an easy way to determine the module's orientation in your PCB, mark pin 1 or add silkscreen markings.

Answer (score 0):

The footprint as shown in the datasheet does not require clearances closer than 0.3mm (0.306 and 0.300 are the tightest) so I think you've got something wrong elsewhere. Maybe try recreating it from scratch.

---

Your updated post shows a module, not the chip in the datasheet. You only have to make pads for a 2.5mm pitch 3-pin connector and leave room for the PCB clearances your fab wants to see.

Use 0.9mm holes (1.0mm is a bit loose I think) and make the pads big enough to get enough spacing. Since it has some mechanical purpose you can go with something like 2.0mm or even 2.2mm for the pads. You can even make them non-round to get more copper, but that's more important when you have a board without plated-through holes.

Comment: Please see updated post.

Comment: @user23342283 Show the footprint you created with critical dimensions. Figure 4 in the data sheet shows the recommended footprint.

Comment: The body of the chip is 4.72mmx3.76mm so the holes would be too big wouldn't they?

Comment: @user23342283:  The 4.72 x 3.76 mm is the size of the microphone device itself.  The SparkFun module is 0.4. x 0.55 inch (10.16 x 13.97 mm).  From the SparkFun picture, it appears the holes are 0.05 inch from the edge of the board - you seem to have them 0.1 inch from the edge.  Your pads look very small to me.  Please verify if you are working with the bare microphone IC or with the SparkFun module.  That makes a BIG difference when discussing the required footprint.

Comment: The sparkfun module.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using a module using the ADMP401 and some supporting circuitry, not a bare ADMP401.  That module just needs a 3 pin 0.1 inch header, not the fancy footprint shown on the ADMP401 datasheet.

You should be able to find a suitable footprint in KiCad's connector library.

If I had to make the footprint, I would use three .060 pads with .040 hole, spaced 0.1 inch apart.

Comment: How can I make them 1 inch apart if the entire board is 4.72mm long and 3.76mm wide?

Comment: The pin spacing is 0.1” (2.54 mm).

Comment: The pin spacing is the same as for GPIO headers on an Arduino, Raspberry Pi, or similar boards

Comment: So the first and third pin should be .1 in apart?

Comment: No - there is 0.1 inch between first and second pin, and 0.1 inch between the second and third pin.  When you get the actual module, the pin spacing should be obvious.

Comment: I have submitted a picture of my created footprint, however, it does not look like the board. Please let me know what I need to change.

Comment: @user23342283: your footprint looks fine to me. A footprint will normally just show the pad/holes for connections and an outline of the part.  For a module like this, it won't show any of the components mounted on the module.  The person making the footprint got fancy and drew some of the parts that are mounted on the module - that is not necessary for KiCad to use the footprint.

Comment: I know that it wont look like the physical part, but even the outline looks wrong. The holes look far away from eachother and the outline of the board.

Comment: @user23342283: do you have the actual Sparkfun module?  If so, you can measure the hole positions on the module and adjust your footprint to suit.  I notice that there is a fourth hole required under the microphone IC to allow sound to pass to the mic.  This is shown on the SparkFun footprint drawing.